# Redondear el menú mobile de bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, navigationview

No se si es posible pero me gustaría saber si se puede poner el menú de bootstrap para móviles con forma redonda. Por defecto viene de forma rectangular y con las puntas redondeadas.

Probé a añadirle a las clases navbar-toggle collapsed y sr-only un border radius pero no le afecta.

El menú que utilizo es el siguiente:

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top menupropio">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>

        <a href="index.html"><img class="logo_menu img-responsive" src="images/logo_peque.png" alt="logo home"/></a>


      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <div class="secciones">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="border-bottom:0px">
          <!--<li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>-->

          <li><a href="kontakt.html" class="head-nav-button nav_graphicdesign">Kontakt</a></li>
          <li><a href="#valik" class="head-nav-button nav_photography">Valik üle 20 aasta jooksul tehtud töödest</a></li> <!--todo los trabajos juntos -->
          <li><a href="#valik" class="head-nav-button nav_photography">Logod</a></li> <!--en esta pagina van todos los logos-->
          <li><a href="#valik" class="head-nav-button nav_photography">Trükised ja muu</a></li> <!--todo lo que no sean logos-->

        </ul>
        </div>
      </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </nav>
```

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La clase que tienes que cambiar es `.navbar-toggle`:

```
.navbar-toggle {
    padding: 14px 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

**DEMO:** https://jsfiddle.net/blonfu/7ok8zu60/

Comment: Ok, gracias! Ya funciona.

Comment: Gracias, es justo lo que estaba buscando.